# How to keep track of and return the head of a linked list in C while adding a node to the end

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list

Currently I have a node struct that looks like the following:

```
struct Node { 
    int data; 
    Node* next; 
};
```

and I want to implement a function that will make a linked list given a list of elements and will return the head of the list. I currently have the following structure:

```
struct Node *make_list(int values[10]) {
    struct Node *curr;
    head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *head;

    head->value = values[0];
    head->next = NULL;
    curr = head;


    for (int i = 1; i < 10 i++) {
        struct Node *tmp;
        tmp->value=values[i];
        curr->next=tmp;
    }
    return head;
}
```

For some reason this code is always returning NULL as the head of the linked list, but after that null element, the 10 elements are in order. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Where is `root` defined?

Comment: whoops that was supposed to be curr

Comment: Your function doesn't have a return statement. Are you sure that's correct? Also, what does this mean: "after that null element, the 10 elements are in order"? What is "after" a NULL?

Comment: For some reason the head element is NULL, but every element after that are the elements in the values array.

Comment: How are you accessing the elements after the head if the head is `NULL`? A `NULL` pointer can't be dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this declaration of node

```
struct Node { 
    int data; 
    Node* next; 
};
```

is invalid in C. You have to declare the structure like

```
struct Node { 
    int data; 
    struct Node* next; 
};
```

Your function definition will not compile and does not make great sense.

It can be defined for example the following way

```
struct Node * make_list( const int values[], size_t n ) 
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node **current = &head;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *current = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

        ( *current )->data = values[i];
        ( *current )->next = NULL;

        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct Node* next; 
}; 

struct Node * make_list( const int values[], size_t n ) 
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node **current = &head;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *current = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );

        ( *current )->data = values[i];
        ( *current )->next = NULL;

        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    return head;
}

void out( struct Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{

    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    struct Node *head = make_list( a, N );

    out( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Vlad's answer (which I think will be simpler to understand):

```
struct Node *make_list(int values[10]) {

  struct Node* head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  head->value = values[0];
  head->next = NULL;

  struct Node *curr;
  curr = head;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      struct Node* tmp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
      tmp->value=values[i];
      tmp->next = NULL;
      curr->next=tmp;
      curr = tmp;
  }
  return head;
}
```

You must always allocate new memory to a new node

`struct Node* tmp = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`

otherwise it will be lost after the function finishes.

Then, you must ensure that you new node receives the correct values:

```
tmp->value=values[i];
tmp->next = NULL;
```

Finally, you need to update your `curr` node, so it points to the last item in the list (usually we call this as `tail`).

```
next=tmp;
curr = tmp;
```

[You can try it out here](https://repl.it/repls/ImperturbableSlimLightweightprocess).